# Number Theory - mod p

Tags: number-theory

Show that if there is no solution $y^2 = x $(mod $p$) then $x^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = -1$ (mod $p$)

I have been given the hint to look at pairs of residues mod $p (a,bx)$ with $ab = 1$ (mod $p$)

Looking for a solution to the problem and motivation behind the solution

Comment: From Fermat's Little Theorem $x^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$, so $x^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \pmod p$ should be a square root of $1$.  Suppose $y^2 \equiv x \pmod p$.  What happens if you raise both sides of that equation to the $(p-1)/2$ power?

Comment: For the second part - follow the hint. How can the partition fail? Show that that particular failure implies a solution to $y^2 \equiv x \pmod{p}$. Hence the partition doesn't fail and it follows through.

Comment: Have used the hint to say that $bx \neq a$ and $b_1 x \neq b_2 x$ and so have reduced the cases to $b_1 x = a_2$ or $b_1 x = b_2$ Not sure where to go from here though. Also have noted that there are $(p+1)/2$ pairs ($a,b$). The problem would imply that $x^{\frac{p+1}{2}} = x (mod \ p)$ and so am trying to show that the product of  all residue pairs $(a,bx) = -x (mod p)$

Comment: should be $x^{\frac{p+1}{2}} = -x$ above

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $x$ is nonsquare mod $p.\,$ For $\,a\not\equiv 0\,$ the map $\,a\mapsto a^{-1}x\,$ is an involution (self-inverse), and has no fixed points (else $\,a \equiv a^{-1} x\,\Rightarrow\ x \equiv a^2)\,$ so it partitions all elts $\not \equiv 0$ into $\color{#0a0}{(p\!-\!1)/2}$ *pairs* $(a,a^{-1}x)$ with product $\color{#c00}x.\,$ So the product $\Pi$ of all elts $\not\equiv 0$ is $\equiv \color{#c00}x^{\color{#0a0}{\large (p-1)/2}}.$ Also  $\,\Pi \equiv (p\!-\!1)!\,\equiv -1\,$ by Wilson's Theorem. Hence we have proved that $x$ nonsquare mod $p$ $\,\Rightarrow\,x^{(p-1)/2}\equiv -1.$

Comment: Is there not $\frac{p+1}{2}$ pairs since 1 and -1 are self inverses? Also could you provide some more detail on why it partitions the residues? Thanks

Comment: @KingJ The elts $\not\equiv 0$ are $\equiv 1,2,\ldots p-1\,$ so there are $p-1$ of them.

Comment: I haven't seen the word "elts" before. What's it's origin? (It's about time we had a word for that set.)

Comment: @Daniel "elt" is an abbreviation of "element"

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that $p$ is an odd prime and $G=\mathbb{Z}/(p\mathbb{Z})^*$. 
$G$ is a cyclic group with order $p-1$, hence there is some $g\in G$ such that every element of $G$ can be represented as $g^k$ with $k\in\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$. The map $\psi:x\mapsto x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ is a [homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism) on $G$ and $\psi(G)$ is a subgroup with exactly two elements, hence for any $h\in G$ we have either $\psi(h)=1$ or $\psi(h)=-1$. If $h=g^{2m}$ we have
$$\psi(h) = \left(g^{2m}\right)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = \left(g^m\right)^{p-1} = 1 $$
and if $h=g^{2m+1}$ we have $\psi(h)=g^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=-1$. It follows that $\ker\psi$ is exactly the subgroup of quadratic residues in $G$. If $y^2\equiv x\pmod{p}$ has no solutions then $x$ is a quadratic non-residue, so $x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=-1$.

Comment: I might have skipped some $\!\pmod{p}$ here and there but I hope the concept is clear enough.

Comment: Do you know a solution to the problem using the hint given?

Comment: @KingJ: the hint is pointing towards the fact that the quadratic residues form a subgroup, and the product of two quadratic non-residues is a quadratic residue (i.e. Legendre symbol is multiplicative). The underlying ideas are more or less the same.

Comment: What is your reasoning for $h = g^{2m+1} \rightarrow -1 $(mod p)?

Comment: @KingJ: the order of $g$ is $p-1$ because $g$ is a generator. $g^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ can only be $1$ or $-1$, but it cannot be $1$ since $g$ is a generator.

Comment: how do we know that the group is cyclic?

Comment: @KingJ: if $\mathbb{K}$ is a finite field then $\mathbb{K}^*$ is a cyclic group. This is a fundamental lemma in most Algebra courses. You may try to prove it on your own by noticing that for any $d\mid(p-1)$ the roots of $\Phi_d(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$ are exactly the elements of order $d$, then by exploiting Moebius inversion formula, for instance.